# Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Tags: database-restore, mysql5.6

MySQL Community-Server 5.6.39
RHEL7
Scenraio:
**Trying to process binary logs to restore the incremental backup and receive `max_allowed_packet error`.**

Turned off binary logs,restarted the database.
Backed up the current schema using.

```
**mysqldump -u root -p --single-transaction --databases nsb > /backup/nsb_backup.sql**
```

Turned on binary logging and restarted the database.

Now I created a new schema called abcd, created two tables abc and xyz in it. Populated the tables with 1M rows.

`insert into abc values (100000, 'ABCDBDHDBFFFL');` and then `insert into abc select * from abc;` 
If I understand it these all changes are recorded in the binary logs.
There were binary logs in the data directory from MYSQLTEST_binlog.000001 to MYSQLTEST_binlog.000010.

Now I dropped the new schema abcd hoping it to restore using binary logs.

Restarted the database:
Tried to restore using

**`$ mysqlbinlog MYSQLTEST_binlog.0000{01..10} > /tmp/test.sql`**

Now I tried to reload the test.sql dump.

**`$ mysql -u root -p < /tmp/test.sql`**

It goes on for some time and I receive the irritating error in the log file 
**`Aborted connection 1 to db: 'abcd' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes)`**

I confirmed the same in the my.cnf file which was already set to 1G in the [mysqld] section. The maximum permissible value for this variable is 1G. I can't raise it further.

Could anyone help me understand what is happening. Is it the repeated inserts causing this issue or anything else?
I checked some forums but all suggest me to check the my.cnf file for max_allowed_packet and they suggest to restart the database.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes

[Mysql - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes) when importing](https://serverfault.com/questions/874457/mysql-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes-when-importing)

[Error 2020: Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes when dumping table](https://serverfault.com/questions/102564/error-2020-got-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes-when-dumping-table)

[Restore (PITR) of CloudSQL (MySQL) fails with Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes](https://serverfault.com/questions/877066/restore-pitr-of-cloudsql-mysql-fails-with-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allo)

[MySQL "max_allowed_packet" error -- how do you profile the max packet size?](https://serverfault.com/questions/243247/mysql-max-allowed-packet-error-how-do-you-profile-the-max-packet-size)

[MySQL max_allowed_packet greater than 1024 MB](https://serverfault.com/questions/344442/mysql-max-allowed-packet-greater-than-1024-mb)

Also most other questions on the web are related to replication and max_allowed_packet. My question is not about replication.